# CSS 3D cube -webkit-transition

Tags: css, 3d, webkit

I was able to reproduce a rotating 3D cube in css using online examples. Now I am analysing the code so I learn the meaning of the code and understand how it works.
However there is one thing i don't understand, I know that the "transition" property lets me add an effect when changing from one style to another. (for example changing the width of an element) But in the code that can be found [here](http://cssdeck.com/labs/uvml2w9a) it's used in a way I don't understand.

```
-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 2s linear;
```

If I leave this piece of code out the cube looks and acts exactly the same, I don't understand what it does and if it is necessary.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-webkit-` is the prefix used on WebKit browsers for properties which do not necessarily have full support and are in a testing/experimentation phase. There are a couple of other prefixes in the CSS world too. A few of the more popular ones are: `-moz-` (Firefox), `-o-` (Opera), and `-ms-` (Internet Explorer).

Here `-webkit-transition:` is the WebKit-prefixed `transition` property, and `-webkit-transform` is the WebKit-prefixed `transform` property.

If we look at Can I Use... for browser support, we'll see that [the `transition` property](http://caniuse.com/#search=transition) requires the `-webkit-` prefix on some mobile browsers. We'll also see that [the `transform` property](http://caniuse.com/#search=transform) requires the `-webkit-` prefix to work on quite a lot of WebKit browsers.

In order to give our `transform` property a `transition` on Android browsers, for example, we'd need to use:

```css
-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 2s linear;
```

On browsers which fully support both `transform` and `transition`, we can achieve the same effect by using:

```css
transition: transform 2s linear;
```

To be on the safe side, we could also cater for browsers which require the WebKit prefix on the `transform` property, but may have since dropped the prefix on the `transition` property - although this may be unnecessary:

```
transition: -webkit-transform 2s linear;
```

---

> The thing I dont understand is what the "transform 2s linear" adds to the cube.

This adds a two second linear transition (animation) to the transform property assigned to the cube. Without this the transform property would be changed immediately, but with this the change is gradual over two seconds.

Here is a [JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/DN5E6/1) I've whipped up of the `transition` property in action. Here our first figure instantly changes from red to green on hover, but our second one takes 2 seconds to change.

The transition in the code you've linked to doesn't appear to have any effect on the object at all.

Comment: I know what the css vendor prefixes mean, that was not the part I didn't understand. The thing I dont understand is what the "transform 2s linear" adds to the cube because if I erase that line of code the cube looks exactly the same. Sorry if my post mislead you, anyways thanks for your answer.

Comment: @user3051847 Ah I see. I've added a bit to the end of my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer again :-). Thanks to your JSFiddle demo I understand what the transition does. But like you said the transition in my code doesn't do anything so I think that line is not necessary in the code and the creater of the demo made a mistake?